# Use multiple functions in Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am wondering how you can separate the handler from the Lambda's core logic. I am always putting all my boto3 code inside the Lambda handler but how to define multiple functions in a Lambda function and use these functions inside the handler ? It seems it is a best practice to do that.

For example:

```
def list_users():
# list iam users here


def list_user_tags():
# list tags of these users here

def something_else():
# do something else


def handler_name(event, context):
# return the result here
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call the other functions from the handler function, such as:

```py
def list_users():
# list iam users here


def list_user_tags():
# list tags of these users here

def something_else():
# do something else


def handler_name(event, context):
  users = list_users()
  tags = list_user_tags(users)

  return something_else(tags)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define a service class that is separate from the handler. Based on the event, you can invoke different methods in service class. You can also extend this idea more via Factory pattern.

```
lambda(event) {
   ...inspect event
   ...instantiate service class
   ...use service class methods to achieve goal
}
```